# css counters and custom components (without shadow dom)

Tags: html, css, custom-component

I am using custom counters in css for print. This works, however, when an h1 tag is inside a custom component, the counter seems to reset.. is this a bug?

Example:
css:

```
h1 {
counter-increment: countH1;
}
```

html:

```
<h1>hello</h1>     -> counter is 1
<h1>hello</h1>     -> counter is 2
<my-component>
  <h1>hello again</h1> -> counter is 1 again :-(
</my-component>
```

Note that my-component is a custom element. This is a customElements.define('my-component', myComponent);  implementation in JS.

Are css counters not compatible with custom components?

John.

Comment: Why do you say "without shadow dom"?

Comment: It appears to be working just fine as seen on [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2oLhb607/5/) Also, if custom components means making your own tag, you most definitely should not be doing that.

Comment: It is a custom element like the ones you would create with polymer or in plain js

Answer (score 1):

You can leave your HTML as is, but try using **:before or :after** by making your CSS look a little something like this.

```
body {
  counter-reset: countH1;
}

h1 {
counter-increment: countMe;
}

h1:before {
  content: counter(countMe, upper-roman);
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the counter does not get incremented.. not that the content is not displayed..

Comment: @JohnGorter did you give the CSS a try? This will get the counter incremented and displays it to show you.

Comment: It actually has to do with the place of the nodes. In my scenario I have three levels of Hx tags (h1, h2, h3). When the h2 tag is inside a div on another level, the h3 further in the document is rendered as 1.0.1 instead of the correct 1.1.1. When I place the h2 tag a level higher (outside of the div it was placed in) then the correct result appears.. Glad to see it has nothing to do with custom elements..